# Open source Web Application Test Automation tool

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications

We are starting on a web application and thinking of TDD development. Can anyone please provide me a list of open source tools to automate our testing.

Thanks in advance
Kaushik

Comment: Are you talking about Unit test? or Functional , Regression test?

Answer (score 2):

First and the most important: [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) Continuous Integration Server (or a CI server from some other vendor).

You can also take a look at a [list of CI servers in comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_continuous_integration_software).

There are also many other tools that ease the process of development using TDD such as:

- Obviously Unit test frameworks (JUnit, TestNG)
- Mocking frameworks (EasyMock, Mockito, PowerMock)

Answer (score 1):

Also, don't forget [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) for building, [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for automating web app testing and [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for load testing.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [cucumber](http://cukes.info/) for BDD, it integrates with [Jenkins](http://www.cheezyworld.com/2011/08/09/running-your-cukes-in-jenkins/) and might help you with your acceptance tests.